# adjust date overlaps within a group

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this table and I want to adjust END_DATE one day prior to the next ST_DATE in case if there are overlap dates for a group of ID

```
TABLE HAVE

ID   ST_DATE         END_DATE
1   2020-01-01     2020-02-01
1   2020-05-10     2020-05-20
1   2020-05-18     2020-06-19
1   2020-11-11     2020-12-01  
2   1999-03-09     1999-05-10
2   1999-04-09     2000-05-10
3   1999-04-09     2000-05-10
3   2000-06-09     2000-08-16
3   2000-08-17     2009-02-17
```

Below is what I'm looking for

```
TABLE WANT

ID   ST_DATE         END_DATE
1   2020-01-01     2020-02-01
1   2020-05-10     2020-05-17  =====changed to a day less than the next ST_DATE due to some sort of overlap
1   2020-05-18     2020-06-19
1   2020-11-11     2020-12-01  
2   1999-03-09     1999-04-08 =====changed to a day less than the next ST_DATE due to some sort of overlap
2   1999-04-09     2000-05-10
3   1999-04-09     2000-05-10
3   2000-06-09     2000-08-16
3   2000-08-17     2009-02-17
```

Comment: I'd do that with a stored procedure rather than a query. Can you try out a stored procedure and add it to your question?

Comment: @zedfoxus - Why? Never do in a procedure what can be done (relatively easily) in a plain SQL statement.

Comment: Never say never @mathguy. I'd do it in a procedure. Your choice may be different than mine and that's OK with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use [LEAD()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions074.htm) for this.  Initial idea:

```
select 
  id, st_date, end_date
, lead( st_date ) over ( partition by id order by st_date ) nextstart_
from overlap
;

-- result
        ID ST_DATE   END_DATE  NEXTSTART
---------- --------- --------- ---------
         1 01-JAN-20 01-FEB-20 10-MAY-20
         1 10-MAY-20 20-MAY-20 18-MAY-20
         1 18-MAY-20 19-JUN-20 11-NOV-20
         1 11-NOV-20 01-DEC-20          
         2 09-MAR-99 10-MAY-99 09-APR-99
         2 09-APR-99 10-MAY-00          
         3 09-APR-99 10-MAY-00 09-JUN-00
         3 09-JUN-00 16-AUG-00 17-AUG-00
         3 17-AUG-00 17-FEB-09
```

Once you have the next start date and the end_date side by side (as it were),
you can use CASE ... for adjusting the dates as you need them.

```
select ilv.id, ilv.st_date
, case 
    when ilv.end_date > ilv.nextstart_ then
      to_char( ilv.nextstart_ - 1 ) || ' <- modified end date'
    else
      to_char( ilv.end_date )
  end dt_modified
from (
  select 
    id, st_date, end_date
  , lead( st_date ) over ( partition by id order by st_date ) nextstart_
  from overlap
) ilv
;

        ID ST_DATE   DT_MODIFIED                            
---------- --------- ---------------------------------------
         1 01-JAN-20 01-FEB-20                              
         1 10-MAY-20 17-MAY-20 <- modified end date         
         1 18-MAY-20 19-JUN-20                              
         1 11-NOV-20 01-DEC-20                              
         2 09-MAR-99 08-APR-99 <- modified end date         
         2 09-APR-99 10-MAY-00                              
         3 09-APR-99 10-MAY-00                              
         3 09-JUN-00 16-AUG-00                              
         3 17-AUG-00 17-FEB-09
```

[DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4c2007db37004c0cc78679e3c073e563) here.

Answer (score 1):

If two "windows" for the same `id` have the same start date, then the problem doesn't make sense. So, let's assume that the problem makes sense - that is, the combination `(id, st_date)` is unique in the inputs.

Then, the problem can be formulated as follows: for each `id`, order rows by `st_date` ascending. Then, for each row, if its `end_dt` is less than the following `st_date`, return the row as is. Otherwise replace `end_dt` with the following `st_date`, minus 1. This last step can be achieved with the analytic `lead()` function.

A solution might look like this:

```
select id, st_date,
       least(end_date, lead(st_date, 1, end_date + 1) 
                       over (partition by id order by st_date) - 1) as end_date
from   have
;
```

The bit about `end_date + 1` in the `lead` function handles the last row for each `id`. For such rows there is no "next" row, so the default application of `lead` will return `null`. The default can be overridden by using the third parameter to the function.